# Переход с C# на C

Tags: c#, c

Здравствуйте!
Хочу изучить С, сам знаю С# на хорошем уровне. Есть пара вопросов.

1. Языки похожи?
2. Выбрал Ритчи, это хорошая книга?

Спасибо!

Comment: чувствую, плеваться замучаетесь, автор. Ни в коем случае не хочу сказать, что С хуже C#, но все же в .NET CLR многое берет на себя, тогда как в С все придется делать самому

Comment: вопрос: вам зачем это?
C# отличный язык, CLR отличная платформа.
Если хотите что то с неуправляемым кодом - не садитесь за это старье, возьмите хотя бы C++.
Они похожи больше и вы сможете писать в стиле C# если захотите.

Comment: зачем это все нужно? может @Вирс планирует написать С под .NET. Для многих это было бы очень интересно. Много старого кода можно было бы легко портировать.

Comment: @Сергей а зачем вообще C# -- у MS (точнее msr) есть отличный язык F# для отличной платформы CLR ((tm)MS)? Не стоит сидеть на этом старье -- C#...

Comment: >> может @Вирс планирует написать С под .NET

Чтобы использовать объектно-ориентированный фреймворк в процедурном языке? Это еще та содомия.

Answer (score 6):

1. Языки совсем на похожи! C# про семантику, объекты, задания и преобразования, C про эффективность, адреса, биты и байты.
2. Ричи -- один из авторов языка. Вы имеете в виду книгу Кернигана и Ричи? Хорошая, практически библия сишника.

Answer (score 5):

1. Синтаксис Си послужил основой для синтаксиса C#. На этом схожесть заканчивается.
2. K&R - сама по себе книга неплохая, но для начинающего будет сложновата. Очень сухая по стилю, сжатая, примеры чересчур сложные, нет упражнений. На русском могу посоветовать С. Прата "Язык программирования С". Но она вышла около 10 лет назад и достать ее теперь непросто, да и в электронном виде в сети не встречал.

Comment: Примеры сложные? Для пятиклассников может и сложные, а для тех, кто изучает второй язык - самое то.

Упражнений нет? Упражнения есть в быдлокнигах типа "изучение с++ за 24 часа для чайников". Короче говоря, не нужны.

Comment: @Flammable, полистал еще раз K&R. Кстати, упражнения есть, почему-то не обращал раньше на этот факт внимания. Так что, K&R - быдлокнига. Не читать ни в коем случае!

Comment: >> Так что, K&R - быдлокнига. Не читать ни в коем случае!

Из моего комментария не следует, что K&R - быдлокнига.

Comment: Нет, следует! По законам формальной логики.

Comment: @mikillskegg, ты не прав. Можешь считать это сливом, если оно повысит твою самооценку.

Comment: Оставьте (кстати, на "ты" мы еще не переходили. И думаю, не перейдем) мою самооценку моему психологу.

>Упражнений нет? Упражнения есть в быдлокнигах типа "изучение с++ за 24 часа для чайников". Короче говоря, не нужны.

Вот абсолютно не вижу логики. Почему, если упражнения есть в быдлокнигах, они не нужны вообще? Единственным обоснованием может быть то, что наличие упражнений - аттрибут быдлокниг и в хороших учебниках их не должно быть.

Answer (score 1):

на хорошем уровне? тогда вопрос о С очень странный.

1. Нет, языки разные. Хотя визуально на первый взгляд кажется, что они похожи.
2. Книги от авторов языка - это хорошо. Но главное, что бы там не был устаревший синтаксис (ещё называется стилем К&R).

Comment: Не думаю, что это странный вопрос:  
1. просто любопытство  
2. Знаешь Си -- знаешь полмира.